# Explode no Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ainda estou com dificuldades no Jquery, diante disso estou trazendo um valor do banco de dados Mysql:

```
<div id="cod_<?php echo $jmValor->IdCodUsuarios; ?>">Nome do usuário</div>
```

Porém preciso fazer tipo o que ocorre com o explode() do PHP, ou seja, retirar o **cod_** e deixar somente o valor vindo do banco. Então fiz dessa forma:

```
var id = valor.split('cod_');
var valor = document.getElementById(id);
$(".conteudoChat").load("chat/?convidar=s&Key="+valor);
```

O que preciso é pegar o valor vindo do banco de dados, colocar o valor na div.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viva!

Penso que seja isto que você quer.
Vai procurar todas as div's que tenham um "id" que comece por "cod_" e insere no conteúdo da div o que estiver a seguir ao prefixo "cod_".

```js
$('[id^="cod_"]').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cod_0001"></div>
<div id="cod_0002"></div>
<div id="cod_0003"></div>
<div id="cod_0004"></div>
<div id="cod_0005"></div>
```

Comment: Olá Hélder. Obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda estou com uma dúvida. Como eu faria para pegar o valor da div, já que é dinâmico e colocar dentro da variável valor?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos por meio de um evento `onchange` no elemento.

Comment: Fiz um alteração no meu post, que penso que pode resolver o seu problema. No entanto se você chama a função no onchange da div como disse o @renan também deve de funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Funcionou!